# cannot sign assembly using sn.exe in msbuild script file

Tags: .net, msbuild, strongname, sn.exe

I used this code to sign assembly in msbuild script file:

```
<Exec Command="$(SNexePath)\sn.exe -R $(TargetPath)\Exchange.dll" />
```

but I've got error:
error MSB3073: The command "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\sn.exe -R D:\Program\Exchange.dll" exited with code 1

After that I executed same command in Visual Studio command prompt to check if it will work with command prompt or not:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\sn.exe -R D:\Program\Exchange.dll
but after that I've got this message:

Option -R takes 2 arguments

How to correctly sign assembly in msbuild script file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sign assembly you need to give sn.exe both assembly and keyfile:

```
<Exec Command="$(SNexePath)\sn.exe -R $(TargetPath)\Exchange.dll Path\To\Keyfile.snk" />
```

Comment: I've did that. First I created keyfile: <Exec Command="$(SNexePath)\sn.exe -k $(KeyFilePath)\keyPair.snk" /> and then <Exec Command="$(SNexePath)\sn.exe -R $(TargetPath)\Exchange.dll $(KeyFilePath)\keyPair.snk" /> but another error ocures: "Exchange.dll does not represent a strongly named assembly"